# Dynamic Dropdown based on table content - remove options from dropdown when deleting contents from table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with inputs and once submitted a dropdown is created based on the contents of inputs. the script i'm using removes duplicates and ignores blanks cells but if you change the the contents of the inputs then it's keeps the same options and adds the new inputs to the dropdown list. Is it possible to reset the dropdown options every time the inputs are submitted by using javascript for a truly dynamic list?

```js
function submit() {

  for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    var inputSelect = document.getElementById("select");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    var select = document.getElementById("input" + i).value

    if (select.trim() !== '') {
      option.text = select
      inputSelect.add(option, inputSelect[0])

      var usedNames = {};
      $("select[name='select'] > option").each(function() {
        if (usedNames[this.text]) {
          $(this).remove();
        } else {
          usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
        }
      });

    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="submit()">submit</button>
<select name="select" id="select">
</select>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <td><input id="input1"></td>
    <td><input id="input2"></td>
    <td><input id="input3"></td>
    <td><input id="input4"></td>
    <td><input id="input5"></td>
    <td><input id="input6"></td>
    </body>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function submit(){
  var inputSelect = document.getElementById("select");
  inputSelect.innerHTML = "";
  for (i=1;i<6;i++){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    var select = document.getElementById("input" + i).value

    if (select.trim() !== ''){
    option.text = select
    inputSelect.add(option,inputSelect[0])
  }
}
```

This way resets the dropdown and then builds it with the input with your for-loop. 
I see you were trying to iterate through the current dropdown and keep values that were still present in the inputs, but this is quicker and easier.

Comment: Yeah you're completely right. this works perfectly, thanks!